# Error in MYSQL DB: Unable to store a Call ID

Tags: mysql, ruby, twilio

#### So I'm using a MySql database to store customer and employee call IDs generated by the Twilio API to then be able to redirect the calls and bridge them by sending requests to that same Twilio API from the script. For example like this:

> `@client = Twilio::REST:Client.new account_sid, auth_token`
>
> `call = @client.account.calls.create({:from => '*OUTGOING*', :to => '*RECIEVEING*', :url => '*URL*', :method => 'GET'})`
>
> `puts call.sid`

Here is what my .sql file looks like:

> `#apply using: mysql < create-twilio.sql`
>
> `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS twilio;`
>
> `CREATE DATABASE twilio;`
>
> `USE twilio;`
>
> `CREATE TABLE calls (`
>
> `created_at DATETIME,`
>
> `updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`
>
> `id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,`
>
> `incoming_Cid INTEGER NOT NULL,`
>
> `conf_Id INTEGER,`
>
> `secondary_Cid INTEGER,`
>
> `ended BOOLEAN,`
>
> `PRIMARY KEY(id),`
>
> `UNIQUE INDEX(incoming_Cid),`
>
> `INDEX(conf_Id),`
>
> `INDEX(secondary_Cid)`
>
> `);`

Before even testing code, when I try to manually modify an incoming_Cid to change it from a random value like '256' to an actual Twilio call id like '**CA9321a83241035b4c3d3e7a4f7aa6970d**'I get an error like:

> `Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)`
>
> `Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1`

How can I fix this to be able to enter call ids like the one above (34 character strings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give incoming_Cid  a CHAR type:

```
incoming_Cid CHAR(34) NOT NULL
```

If it can be bigger than 34, give it a larger value.

Comment: I see, it has to be changed from an integer to a string. Thanks for helping a 16 y/o programming newbie :).